# Render Texture shows opposite view of camera when rendered?

Tags: unity, c#

I am using render texture (cube) to render what camera sees into it. However, the render texture shows me opposite side of cameras view (flipped) instead of what camera sees. Any solution for this?

```
    void Update()
    {
         renderTexture.isPowerOfTwo = true;          
         //Graphics.SetRenderTarget(renderTexture, 0, CubemapFace.PositiveZ);
         renderTexture.dimension = TextureDimension.Cube;
         camera.RenderToCubemap(renderTexture, 63);    
    }
```

What camera sees:
[image]

What Render Texture shows:[image]

What happens when I rotate Render Texture manually by hand 180 degrees: [image]

So, instead of rotating per hand, what I want is for the render texture to be rotated via code so that what is in camera view is shown exactly the same in render texture view.

Comment: Can you show us an example of your output, alongside a view of your scene so we can figure out what output we should expect instead?

Comment: @DMGregory I have updated it.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just the preview window showing you the opposite side of the cubemap? ie. It's looking at the cube projected on a solid ball, viewed from the -z axis, so you see the -z side of the cube, not the +z side that faces toward and captures the sphere in your scene?

Comment: yes the sphere is placed exactly infront of the camera but the render texture captures 360 view of the camera and shows -z axis which is the opposite side of the camera and the sphere is placed on +z axis. I am looking for a way to rotate the render texture cube itself via code.

Comment: Where are you displaying this cubemap at present?

Comment: On a reflection probe.

Comment: And are your reflections backwards? If so, that's the example case we need to see in your question.

Comment: @DMGregory Yes that is the issue.

Comment: @DMGregory I was assuming it was the problem with render texture.

Comment: Don't assume. Always show the actual problem you want to solve. If we gave you a solution for the render texture that didn't fix your reflection probe, then you'd still have a problem. So edit your question to describe and demonstrate the problem with your reflections. It's possible that might have a more efficient solution than rotating the cubemap in code.

Comment: @DMGregory I am sure that it is reflection probe rotation problem. Because when I added the render texture to a skybox/Cubemap material, I can rotate it with the properties under it. Unfortunately there is no rotation option for reflection probe.